# Click on item in listview opens activity with a list based on the item that was clicked in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I'm learning android with a simple app. Is there a way so that when I click on an item in a listview that it goes to a new activity but it contains a certain list specific to the item that was clicked.

For Example:

List 1 ->(ActivityName) Cheese, apples, water

List 2 ->(ActivityName) bread, grapes, soda

List 3 ->(ActivityName) cake, oranges, milk

I know how to open a new activity and pass data with intents but I don't know how to contain a list as 1 item in a listview.

Answer (score 0):

All you do need is to pass a string list to your new activity.

Here is a sample code:

```
ListView lstView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_layout);

// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, lstView);
list.add("Cheese, apples, water");
list.add("bread, grapes, soda");
list.add("cake, oranges, milk");
lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
                adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            // change the background color of the selected element
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

            selectedItemIndex = i;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("info", list.get(i));
            intent.putExtra("selectedTemplateIndex", selectedItemIndex);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

So when the other activity loads you have to fetch the info that you have sent.

```
String contactInfo;
int selectedTemplateIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_contact);

// get the contact info from the contact activity so the user can see the selected contact info
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        contactInfo = extras.getString("info");
        selectedTemplateIndex = extras.getInt("selectedTemplateIndex");
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped make it a lot more simpler than what I was trying to do.

Comment: @chizzyfizzy no problem I am glad it helped you. If you feel like it is an answer to your question, please click on the tick next to it :)